# How can I create this sudden image stretch effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I would like to know how this "melting" or stretched poster effect is created.

[image]

Comment: In my answer below I postulate that the bottom part of the image is not "stretched" as per the other answers. Do you have a higher resolution image available so I can check?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Image from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/_aSOc5RT-8U)

- Increase the canvas vertically from top to bottom:

[image]

- Use the Single Row Marquee Tool

[image: marquee tool]

to make a selection at the image bottom line of pixels:

[image: selection]

- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Win to Transform and scale vertically:

[image]

Comment: may i know how to record gif or screen like you do :) it's well cleaned while i'm new to here using snipping tools :P

Comment: If you are a Mac user, cmd + 4 for screen selection capture. For gif recording I use Kap

Comment: Thanks for reply @Danielillo but i'm afraid that both are for mac so any alternative suggestion for windows? :)

Comment: found one called licecap https://www.cockos.com/licecap/  :) and for clips i think i should continue with snipping tool haha :)

Comment: @DesignPhoenix, you should try https://www.screentogif.com

Answer (score 6):

**Strech Only Maybe**

**This can be done in just 5 minutes**

==> Select 1 or 2 pixel line from bottom via `select tool`

[image]

==> press `ctrl/cmd + t` to **transform** selection.

[image]

==> drag below and enter to save your result :)

[image]

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 6):

I thought it was a bottom selection that was stretched like the other two answers from esteemed users here, but on closer inspection, it is not. There are light lines and dark lines that do not match the image, not at the bottom, and not anywhere else.

[image]

So I must (somewhat pedantically) conclude that those lines were achieved by carrying out the "stretching a portion of the image" trick from the other answers to a different, maybe similar image, or else they were hand generated by generating lines on a black background and varying their outer-glow and opacity settings.

In fact the contrast of the "lines" area is quite high, so I think it probably was hand generated.

In the following image I:

1. Created a black background later
2. Made a small square (although that's not important) selection on a new later and filled it white
3. Made more of these white squares fast by <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>left click</kbd> on a white square to select it and then <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>left click</kbd> and drag to create a new matching layer
4. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to make each layer a new random width
5. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to stretch the selections vertically full height
6. Vary the opacity of each layer
7. Apply gaussian blur to the total

Sounds like a lot, but when you know your keyboard shortcuts it was less than a minute of work, of course your example has more detail

[image]

Comment: The lines don't have to match *anything* else other than the last row of pixels. That last row can be sufficiently different from the row above to make it seem like the lines don't match. Furthermore, you're inspecting the pixels of a .jpg image which has suffered compression artefacts.

Comment: @rootlocus Yes, I am aware of that, but I think the differences in OP's image are so prominent that the last "area" (or line) stretching technique was not employed. I can't prove it of course, but it's my opinion.